# I want to insert two different table row values into single table,

Tags: php, mysql

l have two table "member_registration" and "mebership_details" get row values from two tables using foreign key and move to another single table "existing_members", original row values to be delete.

```
$query=mysql_query("existing_member(member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date,)
SELECT member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date FROM member_registration
WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'"); 
 $query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (member_type) SELECT membership_type FROM membership_details
WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'");

if($query and $query2)
{ //echo "connected";
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM member_registration WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'");
$sql1=mysql_query("delete from membership_details where member_id='".$memberid."'");
    echo "<script>
                alert('Data Deleted Successfully');
                window.location.href='close_member.php';
                </script>"; 
}
```

this is my query, single query  but how to execute both query to insert values from two tables into single table,

Answer (score 1):

You can try union

example below

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, col3) (
select col1 as col1, col2 as col2, col3 as col3 from table2
union
select col1 as col1, col2 as col2, col3 as col3 from table3)
```

careful on the id (primary key or unique) it might already exist or you can use the insert ignore

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

try writing your query like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

this should insert multiple records

if the table is always going to have the two values in the table and you want them in two columns you could do somthing like this:

```
$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (member_type) VALUES (SELECT membership_type FROM membership_details WHERE member_id='".$memberid."' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0, SELECT membership_type FROM membership_details WHERE member_id='".$memberid."' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)");
```

Just Re-Read the question:

```
$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date) VALUES (SELECT member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date FROM member_registration WHERE member_id='".$memberid."')");
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: i need to copy from two table values and insert into one single table, can u suggest me? for example "member_registration" and "mebership_details" get the values using foreign key, and insert into "existing_members" table.

Comment: So the two values are both in membership_details if i'm correct yes?

Comment: Also could there be more than 2 values in this table?

Comment: yes, have more values from membership_details, like(membership_type, joining_date, expiry_date)

Comment: if the above edit didn't help, please could you provide better detail of what you would like to achive with this query...

Answer (score 0):

try using something like this with **join**:

```
"INSERT INTO existing_member (member_type)
 SELECT a.membership_type as member_type FROM membership_details a
 INNER JOIN member_registration c ON c.member_id = a.member_id
 where a.member_id='".$memberid."'"
```

Comment: it's work fine, but how can i insert "member_registration" values within this query,                                                                                                                                                                "$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date)
 SELECT member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date FROM member_registration
 WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'" ); "

Comment: you need to do join as i have mentioned on the foreign key field and select the required values only which you want to insert.you are already using member_registration do you want membership_details also or what.

Comment: just i need to insert values from "member_registration" and "membership_details" into "existing_members" table, example: `insert from  table1 values and table2 values into table3`

Comment: post all the columns of membership_details also i'll write the sql as per.

Comment: the sql in answer is a demo of the structure you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

suchit, i tried this code,

```
`<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 0);
 include 'connection/db_connection.php';
 $memberid=$_POST['memberid'];
  $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_membe(member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date)
SELECT member_id,member_name,dob,gender,address,city,state,phone,email,height,weight,bmi,bp,medical,image_path,joining_date FROM member_registration
WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'" ); 

/*
$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (membership_type) SELECT membership_type  FROM membership_details
WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'"); */

$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO existing_member (membership_type)
 SELECT a.membership_type as membership_type FROM membership_details a
 INNER JOIN member_registration c ON c.member_id = a.member_id, c.member_name=a.member_name
where a.member_id='".$memberid."'");

if($quer and $query2)
{ 
    $sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM member_registration WHERE member_id='".$memberid."'");
    $sql1=mysql_query("delete from membership_details where member_id='".$memberid."'");

    echo "<script>
                alert('Data Deleted Successfully');
                window.location.href='close_member.php';
                </script>"; 
} 
else
{
echo "User Data Already Exist";
}

?>`
```